# Catching and handling Web Browser Close Event

Tags: c#, events, webbrowser-control

I am Using Windows Forms and a WebBrowser Control, I am in need of catching and handling the WebBrowser Controls call to close.

I have looked at this but it is not working as I need it to: http://blogs.artinsoft.net/Mrojas/archive/2009/05/21/Extended-WebBrowser-Control-Series-WebBrowser-Control-and-windowClose().aspx

This is the message I get:

```
---------------------------
Web Browser
---------------------------
The webpage you are viewing is trying to close the window.

Do you want to close this window?
---------------------------
Yes   No   
---------------------------
```

I need to catch this event and suppress it, then perform a function after that. Does anyone know a simple way to do this?

Comment: There is an EXCELLELNT Article here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/71592/How-to-easily-capture-the-NewWindow3-event-and-det this works but is catching the event too late, I need to catch the event before the messagebox is presented to the user.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After searching everywhere and not really getting what I needed, I managed to stumble onto a by chance reference:

```
HtmlDocument htmlDocument = this.webBrowser1.Document;
htmlDocument.Window.Unload += new HtmlElementEventHandler(Window_Unload);
```

The Document does get Unloaded before the WebBrowser Control is closed and disposed.

```
void Window_Unload(object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs e)
{
    // Do your stuff here...
    // Call Method...
    // Close Form...
}
```

And this is now working for me.

Comment: I cannot get this working. Which method did you place the reference?

Comment: Its all standard Windows Forms Application references and Using Statements. I think at the time I may have been using .Net 3.5 but its all standard .Net Architectecture for Windows. Have tested in .Net4 and works fine also.

Comment: Nice thing! Unluckily this event is called even when you refresh or navigate to another web page...

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're closing this window by Javascript. Basically this is security reason. You can't close a window unless it is opened by a script itself. Possible solution could be use this Javascript code

```
function CloseWindow()
{
   window.open('','_self','');
   window.close();
}
```

Here is link to the same example

https://msmvps.com/blogs/paulomorgado/archive/2007/11/02/how-to-close-browser-windows-in-windows-internet-explorer-7.aspx

But I am not sure of all versions of IE.