# WebBrowser Close event without message

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, internet-explorer, browser

I'm making a Facebook share in C#, but when i share a link the Facebook force close the Window and shows the message: "The webpage you are viewing is trying to close the window. Do you want to close it?".

How can i remove this message?

I already tried this: [Catching and handling Web Browser Close Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14742498/catching-and-handling-web-browser-close-event) but don't work.

My code to share is:

```
public void doShare(string url)
    {
        string shareURL = "http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=" + url;
        wb.Navigate(shareURL);
        while (wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
        wb.Document.GetElementById("u_0_0").InvokeMember("click");
    }
```

Comment: Is this server-side code?

Comment: No, it isnt a server-side

Answer (score 1):

Catch the [WindowClosing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768352%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) event, set the Cancel flag to true, and then simply close your form yourself.

Comment: I'm using System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser and dont have this event.

Comment: For what it's worth, the event's there, even if .NET isn't exposing it. When you say "ExtendedWebBrowser" are you referring to this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/13615956/126229